# Trouble copying CSV data using the field_optionally_enclosed_by param

Tags: amazon-s3, delimiter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a two line CSV file below:

```
id, name, value1, alias, user, description, start_time, end_time
24,"quick brown fox, lazy dog",73.0,xyz,username,None,2020-03-16 12:00:00,2020-03-17 19:07:10
```

The file is already in S3 and I've copied other files successfully using the below command. The problem is that on copy to snowflake, the command breaks *I think* due to the second field containing a comma. I'm looking for assistance in troubleshooting this.

The table is defined as:

```
id:int, 
name:text, 
value1:numeric, 
alias:text, 
user:text, 
description:text, 
start_time:timestamp, 
end_time:timestamp
```

And the copy to snowflake command is defined as:

```
COPY INTO schema.table FROM s3://bucket1/
files = ('filepath/filename.csv')
credentials =(aws_key_id='XXXXXXX' aws_secret_key='XXXXXXX')
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1
field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"' null_if = ('\N', 'None', 'nan'));
```

Running it yields the following error:

```
Error: Number of columns in file (1) does not match that of the corresponding table (9), use file format option error_on_column_count_mistmatch=false to ignore this error
```

I look forward to any advice on moving forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your test CSV has a slight anomaly from how apps would write out standard CSV. Snowflake is being told that the fields are optionally enclosed by double quotes, but that's not precisely right.

On the right side your second column is enclosed by a double quote, but on the left side it's enclosed by a **space** and double quote.

If you try with these lines with the spaces removed (since any app writing out a CSV would format it without spaces), it should work for you.

```
id,name,value1,alias,user,description,start_time,end_time
24,"quick brown fox, lazy dog",73.0,xyz,username,None,2020-03-16 12:00:00,2020-03-17 19:07:10
```

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your response. I've confirmed there are no spaces between fields. In addition, adding the TRIM_SPACE = TRUE parameter in the file format should resolve that issue if that were indeed the case, yet the same error occurs.

Comment: TRIM_SPACE = TRUE doesn't help, actually.  That would occur after the parser determines that the value of the field is inside the optional quotes.

Comment: It seems the Snowflake docs disagree. "For example, if your external database software encloses fields in quotes, but inserts a leading space, Snowflake reads the leading space rather than the opening quotation character as the beginning of the field (i.e. the quotation marks are interpreted as part of the string of field data). Set this option to TRUE to remove undesirable spaces during the data load."

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: Again, I don't think the issue is in spaces as I've confirmed there are no spaces between the comma separated values.

Comment: I'm able to load the file, but only when eliminating the spaces that were in the sample you provided. This is the file format I'm using: ALTER FILE FORMAT "TEST2"."PUBLIC".LATEST2 SET COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 1 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' TRIM_SPACE = FALSE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ('\\N');

Comment: @zzzzzzzch *"there are no spaces between the comma separated values"* is simply untrue, or the data in your question does not actually match the file under consideration. `24,<space>"quick...` is how your first row of data begins, and this is malformed, invalid CSV by any reasonable standard.

Comment: Thank you Greg. I will try to replicate your success. @Michael-sqlbot I have edited the post to reflect the current state of the file. However, again, TRIM_SPACE=TRUE would eliminate any leading spaces if this were the problem. It is not th eproblem.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue:

```
file_format = (type='CSV', SKIP_HEADER=1, ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD ='None', FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"', SKIP_BLANK_LINES=True)
```